# Should I save a password to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, security, object, password-protection

I read a book where an example deploys a javascript object in Node.js , in order to save and edit a User.

Is it safe to save the hashed password to an object, even if it is back-end? I think is a good practice to hash it and save it, not keep it around in an object, because I guess it will maybe be accesible.

In a simpler project I used Apache and synchronous PHP, so I got the password, hash it and save it in the database. It feels risky to me to store it in an object. I am used to keeping the id of the user in a session, so I know who she is, and thats it.

So, is it safe to keep it in an object or am I overeacting here?

This is the book's code

```
function User(obj){
  for (var key in obj)
  {this[key]=obj[key;]}
}


User.prototype.save = function (fn){
  var user = this;
  user.hashPassword(function (err){
    var id = user.id;
    //save user on redis...
  })
}

User.prototype.hashPassword = function (fn){
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(12, function(err,salt){
  user.salt = salt;
    bcrypt.hash(user.pass, salt, function(){
      user.pass = hash;
     fn();
    })
  })
```

To test this I add

```
var tobi = new User({
    name:'tobi',
    pass:'im a ferret'
});

tobi.save(function (err){
    if (err)throw error;
})
```

and then hit on the console `node folder/filename.js`

The book is "Node.js in Action", 
*Mike Cantelon, Marc Harter, T.J. Holowaychuk and Nathan Rajlich*, Manning Publications, ©2014, pp. 233-236

Thanks!

Comment: You mean hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, thank you, I will edit  right now

Comment: There's nothing wrong with objects. The things that matter: Where is the objects stored/sent to? Whose password is it?

Comment: As long as it isn't visible in front end, you could safely operate on it in NodeJS without restrictions :)

Comment: @SzybkiSasza What it would make it visible in the front-end? Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: I meant passing user object e.g. in request to client side. If you operate on object only on backend-side you should not worry. Of course, storing object in any database requires hashing/encrypting etc. Objects in NodeJS are as safe as in any other language/framework and aren't easily accessible outside of application scope.